# Unable to log onto azure web site but OK on local server

Tags: c#, .net, azure, connection

Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 116.

The connection string is:-

```
connectionString="Server=tcp:*******.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=*******;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;User ID=bill;Password=&quot;**************&quot;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not
> conform to specification starting at index 116.]
> System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String
> connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean
> useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +6047798
> System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
> parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
> synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +127
> System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
> Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +100
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
> connectionString) +61
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
> connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +29
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
> key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
> userConnectionOptions) +169
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
> key) +63
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
> +93    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__18(DbConnection
> t, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 c) +12    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
> target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1
> interceptionContext) +360
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings
> appConfigConnection) +269
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String
> name, AppConfig config) +32
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +129
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
> +13    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName() +11
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext
> context) +92
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
> +515    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +20    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
> entityType) +16
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53    System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
> +15    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +38    System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1
> source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +138    System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1
> source, Expression`1 predicate) +145    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__67.MoveNext() +402    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> +59    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__24.MoveNext()
> +309    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +102
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +64    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func) +160    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManagerExtensions.PasswordSignIn(SignInManager`2
> manager, String userName, String password, Boolean isPersistent,
> Boolean shouldLockout) +127    Unisports.Account.Login.LogIn(Object
> sender, EventArgs e) in
> E:\Unisports\Unisports\Unisports\Account\Login.aspx.cs:37
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9794234
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
> eventArgument) +211
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
> eventArgument) +12
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
> sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
> +35    System.Web.UI.d__523.MoveNext() +5951

Comment: This has been working well for some time but just happened when I added a new web page.

Answer (score 0):

After 4 days of frustration I deleted the entire project and web app service from azure and reinstalled it and it worked ok.